# Laravel 404 issue on server

Tags: apache, laravel

I have a Laravel site that is running fine on local while on server, it gives 404 error for some links.

e.g. when I click Add to Cart, it takes me to /store/cart/add/. (The routes.php suggests that it should be https://www.example.com/cart/add) But on localhost I have this application running on the path `/var/www/html/store/...` and is working fine. 
Also links to the images have also been broken.

Here is my routes.php

```
 /** Get the view for Cart Page **/
    Route::get('/cart', array(
        'before' => 'auth.basic',
        'as'     => 'cart',
        'uses'   => 'CartController@showCart'
    ));

    /** Add items in the cart **/
    Route::post('/cart/add', array(
        'before' => 'auth.basic',
        'uses'   => 'CartController@addCart'
    ));

    /** Update items in the cart **/
    Route::post('/cart/update', [
        'uses' => 'CartController@update'
    ]);

    /** Delete items in the cart **/
    Route::get('/cart/delete/{id}', array(
        'before' => 'auth.basic',
        'as'     => 'delete_book_from_cart',
        'uses'   => 'CartController@delete'
    ));
```

here is my .conf file on the server:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/store/
         ServerName www.example.com

        <Directory /var/www/store/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/errorstore.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/accessstore.log combined
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

what could be the reason? and how can I correct it?

**Update:**  My .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

CartController@addCart

```
Cart::create(
            array (
                'user_id'    => $usr_id,
                'product_id' => $prod_id,
                'quanty'        => $quantity,
                'total'      => $ttl
            )
        );

        // then redirect back
        return redirect()->route('cart');
```

Comment: Can you place index.php infront of your cart/add to see whether your .htaccess is the problem?

Comment: What do you have in `CartController@addCart` ?

Comment: please see the Update section for .htaccess

Comment: Have you removed `public` folder or there?

Comment: I have checked your site and it shows me below form<br/>
`<form action="/store/cart/add" method="post" name="add_to_cart">`
`</form>`
url is showing `/store/cart/add` here `store` is main project folder

Comment: Oops!.. such a big nonsense on my part. It was 'hard-coded' that's why.. .Anyhow.. can you please suggest me what could be the reason the images are not being displayed?

Comment: There also you have added `/store/src/public/ProductPhotos/` remove `/store` you will find image

Comment: :) Thanks.. my gratitude